# execve() when used with "which" is not outputting to terminal

Tags: c, bash, terminal, execve

I am attempting to retrieve the path of a command line argument I pass through to a program.
e.g

```
running ./a.out results.txt cat should give me /bin/cat but gives me nothing
running ./a.out results.txt wc should give me /usr/bin/wc but gives me nothing
running ./a.out results.txt sdfasfd results in No such file or directory
```

basically I am trying to reproduce the "which cat" or "which wc" etc command line.
I am running the following test

```
    void runtest(char **argv)
    {
      char *args[3];
      args[0] = "/usr/bin/which";
      args[1] = argv[2];
      args[2] = NULL;
      printf("EXECUTING \n");
      execve(args[0], args, NULL);
      perror("");
    }
```

I am however not getting any output in terminal of path.
I would appreciate if somebody could advise me why the above does not workhow to retrieve the path for the command/executable passed through to the program based on above test function WITHOUT any new additional functions (I have strict restrictions for my assignment and can only use execve and if I must, access().

Once the path is retrieved I will be using it in another function to actually run the command on the file passed through to program as per ./a.out results.txt cat.
I cannot hardcode the path as cat, wc and others dont always share the same Path.
Thank you

Comment: Since which relies on the PATH environment variable, pass the pointer on the environment to execve(): extern char **environ; execve(args[0], args,  environ);

Answer (score 1):

The manual page execve(2) [says](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html):

> On Linux, `argv` and `envp` can be specified as `NULL`.  In both cases, this has the same effect as specifying the argument as a pointer to a list containing a single null pointer.  Do not take advantage of this nonstandard and nonportable misfeature!  On many other UNIX systems, specifying `argv` as `NULL` will result in an error (`EFAULT`).  Some other UNIX systems treat the `envp==NULL` case the same as Linux.

So, even if you're on Linux, you're setting an empty environment that doesn't contain even a `PATH` variable, so the search fails. On my system, an error is printed by `which`:

```
/usr/bin/which: no cat in ((null))
```

It works if you use `execv` instead, which doesn't require an environment and just inherits it from the parent process:

```
        execv(args[0], args);
```

Comment: yes that was it thank you, I managed to navigate this issue without introducing new functions by passing through the envp argument to my main function and to this test function as per below
void runtest(char **argv, char **envp)
{
 char *args[3];

 args[0] = "/usr/bin/which";
 args[1] = get_command(argv[2]);
 args[2] = NULL;
 printf("EXECUTING %s\n", args[1]);
 execve(args[0], args, envp);
 perror("");

}